# Which parameter determines the transformer size in a forward converter?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics

Upon enquiring for a 100W forward converter transformer, the vendor quickly suggested an EFD30 core. Does the size EFD30 represent the size of core as well as window area?

As far as I remember from [text books](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/course/%7Eemlab/assets/tfdesign.pdf), it is the area product (Core area * Window area) which depends on Power transfer level.

Comment: Can you please delete the almost-duplicate question?

Answer (score 2):

> *Does the size EFD30 represent the size of core as well as window area?*

"EFD30" commonly used actually means "EFD30/15/9" because that specific size core dominates the EFD range in applications. So for EPCOS, their version of the EFD30/15/9 is this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1872310.pdf). And, from Ferroxcube it's this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/a220/0900766b811dfdb4.pdf). As you can see, they are dimensionally the same.

However, each can be made from different ferrite material and can be pre-gapped by the supplier as per this Ferroxcube table: -

[image]

So, the real wisdom is knowing what you want from a material standpoint. If you really want to get this right you need to look at the details. The Ferroxcube data sheet does contain important loss information vs frequency vs field levels vs materials.